# Match IDs of different tables from API

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

For example, i have a v-for with user data to show in a table, and on each user i have a store_id, but what i want to show is the store name  that is in another table (that comes with a different endpoint). So i have in both tables store_id but i cant figure out a way to "connect" them.

```
 <tbody>
   <tr v-for="user in users">
       <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
       <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
       <td>{{ user.store_id }}</td> //here i want the store name of /api/stores endpoint
    </tr>
                
</tbody>
```

```
<script setup>

    const { data: users } = await useFetch('/api/users')

    const { data: stores } = await useFetch('/api/stores/' +id) //how to do it?

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a method to return the name of the given store_id

```html
<td>{{ getStoreName(user.store_id) }}</td>
```

and then create the method:

```js
const getStoreName = (id) => {
  const store = stores.find(s => s.id === id)
  if (store) {
    return store.name
  } else {
    return 'no matching store'
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it was what i was looking for! Just a quick note, when doing stores.find it was stores.value.find